# Shell script help

Tags: bash, script, command-line

I am new to writing shell scripts for Unix and need a little help. I am not sure why cURL now all of the sudden after running the script is downloading corrupts packages which cannot be mounted and why running the commands separately in Terminal work, but during the script everything fails such as

For cURL it comes back saying command not found
For the mv command it says cannot find file or directory
and of course mounting and everything thereafter fail.

Could you please take a look at the shell script to see what is missing or I am doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/sh
#Machines must have cURL installed as a prerequisite to download software from internet or FTP server 

# grab files from www.teamviewer.com or custom FTP server
curl -O http://download.teamviewer.com/download/TeamViewerHost.dmg

# grab TeamViewer from custom FTP server
curl -O https://www.dropbox.com/s/***********/com.TeamViewer8.Settings.plist

# Wait for download
sleep 30s

# Place customized plist file into Library/Preferences
mv ~/Downloads/com.TeamViewer8.Settings.plist /Library/Preferences/

# Mount and Install TeamViewer
hdiutil mount ~/Downloads/TeamViewerHost.dmg
installer -pkg /Volumes/TeamViewerHost/Install\ TeamViewerHost.pkg -target /

# Unmount package
hdiutil unmount /Volumes/TeamViewerHost/
```

Comment: Add a `set -eux` to the top of your script. This will lead to it stopping when the first command fails.

Comment: That’s not an FTP server if the URL starts with http/https.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. I don't have time currently to explain the changes/additions, but I'll update. You must run this script as sudo for it to work.

Even easier, `sudo chmod +s yourscript` - will run as root without requiring password.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Machines must have cURL installed as a prerequisite to download software from internet or FTP server 

#Change to your working directory. 
cd ~/Downloads

#grab files from www.teamviewer.com or custom FTP server
curl -O http://downloadus3.teamviewer.com/download/TeamViewerHost.dmg

#grab TeamViewer from custom FTP server
curl -O https://www.dropbox.com/s/******/com.apple.TeamViewer8.Settings.plist

#Place customized plist file into Library/Preferences
mv ~/Downloads/com.apple.TeamViewer8.Settings.plist /Library/Preferences/

#Mount and Install TeamViewer
hdiutil mount ~/Downloads/TeamViewerHost.dmg
installer -pkg /Volumes/TeamViewerHost/Install\ TeamViewerHost.pkg -target LocalSystem

#Softkill process in order to unmount package
ps aux | grep -i TeamViewer | awk {'print $2'} | xargs kill

#Unmount package
hdiutil unmount /Volumes/TeamViewerHost/
```

Comment: Only thing is, you need to cd as ~/Downloads and also you can just get rid of `sleep 30s`. Good softkill workaround

Comment: Thanks for input. Why `cd ~/downloads`? I don't see the need, other than perhaps tightening it up. The indicated links automatically download into ~/Downloads, without any `cd` needed. Regards.

Comment: Well, they /don't/ download automatically to that folder. They automatically download to ~, at least on my macbook.

Comment: This doesn't work well in all but the narrowest of cases. The files are downloaded to the current working directory. Your `mv` calls assume a fixed download location. Sudo should not be necessary. The commands that need elevated privs will prompt for them if they are required here. Also: you have no error checking. What if the curl calls fail?

Comment: @IanC. Thanks for input. I've modified based on Steve's suggestions as well. Immediately removed sudo from the script...quickly realized that was stupid. Adding conditional expressions in case of failure of curl calls would make a great deal of sense...too tired now though. Tomorrow! Thanks for your feedback. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for all the help guys! I am in the process of updating the script now and will re-post after taking all of your comments into play.  @njboot what is the purpose of the line 'ps aux | grep -i TeamViewer | awk {'print $2'} | xargs kill' because when I ran it through the terminal manually it turned the screen blank and I could not escape from it?

Comment: @gogo When you mount the image and install the software, the app and processes associated with the image run - as a result, the last step (unmounting) fails without killing these processes first.

Answer (score 7):

> For cURL it comes back saying command not found

You need to solve this first. cURL ships default with OS X 10.9 and should be in your `PATH` assuming you haven't monkey with your `PATH` environment variable. Try calling it directly with:

```
/usr/bin/curl
```

in the script instead. Also:

```
which curl
```

in a Terminal will show you the full path to the `curl` command in your current environment.

Regarding:

```
curl -O http://download.teamviewer.com/download/TeamViewerHost.dmg
```

The `-O` option tells curl to save the output to a file *in the current working directory*. That means if you're not in `~/Downloads` when you run that command, the file isn't saved to `~/Downloads`. You should add a:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

line before calling the curl commands or use `-o <filename-with-a-path>` to save the file to a specific location with a specific name.

You should also wrap the URLs in quotes (`"`) -- this stops shell special characters in the URLs like `&` from being interpreted by the shell and causing the URL sent to curl to be incorrect.

This:

```
sleep 30s
```

in completely unnecessary. The curl calls won't return until they've completely downloaded the files. Note: they'll return if they *fail* to download the files as well. You may want to consider [checking the ext codes of the curl calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195607/checking-bash-exit-status-of-several-commands-efficiently) or for the existence of the files after calling curl to make sure they ran correctly. Or consider adding `set -e` to the top of the script so that [the script exits if any command returns a non-zero exit code](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_06.html).

Finally:

> For the mv command it says cannot find file or directory and of course mounting and everything thereafter fail.

Your `mv` call is failing because your curl calls are failing and aren't downloading the files as expected. Fix the curl calls and you'll fix the `mv` call.

Comment: He had a problem with `mv` that would fix the problem with `curl` when it was rectified. However good post!

Comment: @Steve I quoted his post in my answer. He said "For cURL it comes back saying command not found".

Comment: Fixed my comment, sorry I worded it wrongly

Comment: Fixing `mv` still wouldn't help if he's getting `command not found` trying to call `curl` from his script.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
#!/bin/sh
#Machines must have cURL installed as a prerequisite to download software from internet or FTP server 

# grab files from www.teamviewer.com or custom FTP server
cd ~
curl -O http://downloadus3.teamviewer.com/download/TeamViewerHost.dmg

# grab TeamViewer from custom FTP server
curl -O https://www.dropbox.com/s/***********/com.TeamViewer8.Settings.plist

# Place customized plist file into Library/Preferences
mv ~/com.TeamViewer8.Settings.plist /Library/Preferences/

# Mount and Install TeamViewer
hdiutil mount ~/TeamViewerHost.dmg
installer -pkg /Volumes/TeamViewerHost/Install\ TeamViewerHost.pkg -target /

# Unmount package
hdiutil unmount /Volumes/TeamViewerHost/
```

---

Your link to download TeamviewerHost returned

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="http://downloadus3.teamviewer.com/download/TeamViewerHost.dmg">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

when I read the file, so I changed the link.

Comment: That first `curl` call will download the file to the directory you happen to be in when the script is run, not to `~` as the `mv` command is expecting. Better to `cd ~/Downloads` at the start of the script so you're in a known location.

Comment: Also: no error checking.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all the help guys. Taking everything into account from the awesome suggestions thanks to Steve, Ian, orkoden and njboot here is the result of the script which works. I wish I knew how to apply the error checking that Ian had suggested so I added the set -eux.

```
#!/bin/sh
#sudo chmod +s "scriptname" - will run as root without requiring password
#Machines must have cURL installed as a prerequisite to download software from internet or FTP server 

#Stop script when first command fails
set -eux

#Change to your working directory. 
cd ~/Downloads

#grab TeamViewer version 8.dmg package and plist files from custom FTP server or TeamViewer website
curl -O "https://www.dropbox.com/s/*************/com.TeamViewer8.Settings.plist" #file located in location ~/Library/Preferences/
curl -O "https://www.dropbox.com/s/*************/com.teamviewer.teamviewer.plist" #file located in location ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
curl -O "https://www.dropbox.com/s/*************/com.teamviewer.teamviewer_desktop.plist" #file located in location ~/Library/LaunchAgents/

#version 8 download first for installation prior to version 9
curl -O "http://download.teamviewer.com/download/version_8x/TeamViewerHost.dmg"

#Place customized plist file into Library/Preferences and Library/LaunchAgents/
mv ~/Downloads/com.TeamViewer8.Settings.plist ~/Library/Preferences/
mv ~/Downloads/com.teamviewer.teamviewer.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
mv ~/Downloads/com.teamviewer.teamviewer_desktop.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/

#Mount and Install TeamViewer version 8
hdiutil mount ~/Downloads/TeamViewerHost.dmg
installer -pkg /Volumes/TeamViewerHost/Install\ TeamViewerHost.pkg -target LocalSystem

#Softkill process in order to unmount package
ps aux | grep -i TeamViewer | awk {'print $2'} | xargs kill

#Unmount package
hdiutil unmount /Volumes/TeamViewerHost/

#version 9 upgrade 
cd ~/Downloads
curl -O "http://downloadus3.teamviewer.com/download/TeamViewerHost.dmg"

#Mount and Install TeamViewer version 9
hdiutil mount ~/Downloads/TeamViewerHost.dmg
installer -pkg /Volumes/TeamViewerHost/Install\ TeamViewerHost.pkg -target LocalSystem

#Softkill process in order to unmount package
ps aux | grep -i TeamViewer | awk {'print $2'} | xargs kill

#Unmount package
hdiutil unmount /Volumes/TeamViewerHost/
```

The purpose of the script is to find a way to deploy TeamViewer 9 through ssh and terminal silently without having to install 3rd party software as suggested in the following links:

http://jdmsysadmin.wordpress.com/2013/09/27/configuring-teamviewer-host-to-be-deployable-via-managed-software-update-munki-on-mac-os-x/

http://jdmsysadmin.wordpress.com/2014/04/16/configuring-teamviewer-host-9-to-be-deployable-with-munki/

Answer (score 0):

I would first try putting quotes around your URLs for `curl` and the other commands. Inside the shell script, punctuation can cause issues.

Also change the first line to `#!/bin/bash` instead of sending it to `sh`.

Comment: `/bin/sh` is a full and proper `bash` shell. Has been that way for all the OS X released at least. See `/bin/sh --version` if you doubt this. No need to change the `#!` line.